# Pi usb gps data connection issue with xgps or cgps

Tags: usb, gps

am having a similar issue. I can see that the receiver is getting gps data (lat/long/etc.) by using:
**gpsmon /dev/gps0**

If I query: **gpsmon /dev/ttyUSB0** (there is no reply.)

However: **ls -l /dev/gps0**

returns: lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxx xxx 7 Dec 31 1969 /dev/gps0 -> ttyUSB0

So, I take that to mean those are linked.

Even CuteCom is able to connect to /dev/ttyUSB0 and stream data. But I can't get **cgps -s** or **xgps** to seem to connect to the device. I've terminated all instances, restarted them, rebooted, etc. (many times)

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: well, I have made some progress on it.  I was able to get it to work by trying it on a different distribution (Kali).  works exactly as instructions suggest.  PwnPi is still not liking it for some reason.

Comment: Glad to heat that, @Mark.  I have a similar Q&A that provides some info on the subject which may or may not help you.  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68816/how-can-i-set-up-my-g-mouse-usb-gps-for-use-with-raspbian

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange.  Please take a moment and look at the tour at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.  And when you get the answer to your question, please post it as a full answer, with details so others may follow in your footsteps.

Answer (score -3):

May be it is because rpi lacks a real time clock module. Sync your time first and try again.

Comment: All Pis have a RTC module.  Meanwhile, welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange.  Please take a moment and look at the tour at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.  I see you have downvotes, and they are there for two reasons:  1) you are factually wrong, and 2) this looks like a comment and not an answer.  I realize that with your rep you may not be able to comment, so you would need to provide an answer that is backed up by good solid references.  You can edit this completely or delete it.  But either way, please take the tour.  You are welcome here.